# Using shell script how to add a character in the end of the line skipping header and trailer record

Tags: shell

I have file.txt

0ABCDFILE    20210922
116123414662290120210922AB 1455AMSHREY
116123414662300120210922AC 1455AMSHREY
116123414911020120210922AB 0271AMSAMSJ
116123414912360120210922AR 0271AMSAMSJ
116123414914070120210921AB 0100AMSHKGJ
90000000000005

Would like to add 'F' in end the records skipping header and trailer. Please advise. Thanks

0ABCDFILE    20210922
116123414662290120210922AB 1455AMSHREY**F**
116123414662300120210922AC 1455AMSHREY**F**
116123414911020120210922AB 0271AMSAMSJ**F**
116123414912360120210922AR 0271AMSAMSJ**F**
116123414914070120210921AB 0100AMSHKGJ**F**
90000000000005

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```sh
$ awk 'NR > 1 && NF > 1 { $(NF) = $(NF)"F" } { print }' < file.txt
```